# Maximum X values at array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that takes array, size and number of X maximum grades at the array.
e.g:

```
array = { 90,45,77,43,67,88 }, maxGrades = 3
```

The result should be:

```
retArray = {90,77,88} or {90,88,77}
```

What I have been tried:

```
int * GetMaxGrades(int * grades, int size, int maxGrades)
{
     int *retArray;

     if (maxGrades > size)
        return grades;

     retArray = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int) * maxGrades);

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < maxGrades; j++)
            if (grades[i] > retArray[j])
            {
                 retArray[j] = grades[i];
                 break;
            }
     }

     return retArray;
}
```

But I'm revived `{90,88,67}`

**EDIT**
If I change the inner loop like that:

```
        if (grades[i] > retArray[j])
        {
            if (j + 1 < maxGrades)
                retArray[j + 1] = retArray[j];

            retArray[j] = grades[i];
            break;
        }
```

It solved part of the problem, but is it the best way to do that?

Comment: The simplest answer is to sort the array (in descending order) with `qsort`, and then take the first X items. Alternatively, you need to insert new items at the correct location in your `retArray` so that the array is always sorted.

Comment: You are overwriting 77 with 88, even though 67 is smaller.  You need to replace the smallest value in retArray, not the first one you find.

Comment: `calloc(sizeof(int) * maxGrades)` --> `calloc( maxGrades, sizeof(int))`

Comment: Lets say it was a learning exercise and`qsort` is cheating.  Then your problem is that any new value going into `retArray` has that `break` statement preventing  tests on later indexs inside `retArray`.  Opportunities to find a new maximum could be skipped.  I suspect that replacing `break;` with `grades[i]=0;` would work, but I am too lazy to check.  But it would be pretty brute force then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `grades` array may contain duplicates the solution becomes more difficult. And don't forget that if you return back pointer to `grades` array the caller may not know should or should not it free the returned pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* GetMaxGrades(int* grades, int size, int maxGrades) {
    if (maxGrades <= 0 || size <= 0)
        return NULL;

    // first, function must allocate memory every time,
    // otherwise you can't understand when to free memory or when do not it.
    int *retArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxGrades);

    if (maxGrades >= size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            retArray[i] = grades[i];
        for (int i = size; i < maxGrades; ++i)
            retArray[i] = 0;
    }
    else {
        // need to save positions of found max grades,
        // because if there's duplicates among grades,
        // you will pick up only different onces.
        int *positions = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxGrades);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxGrades; ++i) {
            int position = 0;
            int maxgrade = INT_MIN;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                // pick max grade
                if (grades[j] > maxgrade) {
                    // do not permit duplicates among positions
                    bool newmax = true;
                    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
                        if (positions[k] == j) {
                            newmax = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // assign new max value & position
                    if (newmax) {
                        position = j;
                        maxgrade = grades[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            positions[i] = position;
            retArray[i] = maxgrade;
        }
        free(positions);
    }
    return retArray;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a[] = { 90,45,77,43,67,88 };
    const int max_grades = 3;
    int *p = GetMaxGrades(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_grades; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are allowed to use `qsort` that will become more easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int greater_comp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return *(int*)b - *(int*)a;
}

int* GetMaxGrades(int* grades, int size, int maxGrades) {
    if (maxGrades <= 0 || size <= 0)
        return NULL;

    int alloc_size = (maxGrades < size) ? size : maxGrades;

    // copy grades array (allocate more memory)
    int *retArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * alloc_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        retArray[i] = grades[i];
    for (int i = size; i < alloc_size; ++i)
        retArray[i] = 0;

    // sort: descending order
    qsort(retArray, size, sizeof(int), greater_comp);

    return retArray;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a[] = { 90,45,77,43,67,88 };
    const int max_grades = 3;
    int *p = GetMaxGrades(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_grades; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you would use algorithm library that will become much more easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> GetMaxGrades(vector<int> grades, int maxGrades) {
    // descending order
    sort(grades.begin(), grades.end(), greater<int>());
    grades.resize(maxGrades);
    return grades;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<int> a = { 90,45,77,43,67,88 };
    vector<int> p = GetMaxGrades(a, 3);
    for (auto& i : p)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While it can be done in linear time using selection algorithm, it is usually done using a min-heap that stores the top k elements, at each iteration - you check if the smallest element in the heap is greater or not from the current one you are iterating, and if it is - you replace them.

This is `O(nlogk)` time and only `O(k)` extra memory, and requires only a single traversal on the data (so it'll work perfectly if your elements are coming in a stream).

The following code is C++11 (with its elegant for-each loops), but it's easy to transform it to old c++ code, using the same data structures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main(void) {
    int array[] = { 90,45,77,43,67,88 }; 
    int maxGrades = 3;
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> q;
    for (int x : array) { 
        // populate first maxGrades elements
        if (q.size() < maxGrades) {
            q.push(x);
        // replace if new element is higher than smallest in heap.
        } else if (q.top() < x) {
            q.pop();
            q.push(x);
        }
    }
    // print elements
    std::cout << "elements: ";
    while (!q.empty()) { 
        std::cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the X largest values from an array of size N can be performed in **O(N)** average complexity using the QuickSelect algorithm from the inventor of QuickSort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your last loop iteration your retArray looks like this: `{90,77,67}`. If you step through the inner loop with an `i=5`, you'll find the 77 is found before the 67, so the 77 is the one replaced. You should probably sort the array and take the top maxGrades values, but if you want to do it your way:

```
for(...)
    if(grades[i] > retArray[j])
        if(retArray[j] < retArray[minVal])
            minVal = j;
if(minVal > 0)
    retArray[minVal] = grades[i];
minVal = -1;
```